# Json string returned by the success function doesn't work but hard coding works

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to bind json data to a chart. JSON string is generated on the server side.
Following is the generated JSON string.

```
{ labels: ["Northern", "South Western", "Western", "North Eastern", "Eastern"], datasets: [{ label: '2016 - 2017', backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5)', pointBorderColor: '#fff', data: [3762714, 11079381, 6223980, 2253066, 2772093] }, { label: '2016 - 2018', backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5)', pointBorderColor: '#DEB816', data: [3762714, 11079381, 6223980, 2253066, 2772093] }, ] }
```

if I assign above string directly to the chart data it works!

but if I assign the data returned by the success function, it doesn't work.

```
   var fetch_url;
    fetch_url = '../CMSWebParts/VLine/VTell/MapCoords.aspx/LoadBarChart';
    return $.ajax({
        url: fetch_url,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (res, textStatus) {

            var parsedString = JSON.stringify(res.d);

            console.log(res.d);

            //This one works, this is the exact string returned by "res.d"
            var barData = { labels: ["Northern", "South Western", "Western", "North Eastern", "Eastern"], datasets: [{ label: '2016 - 2017', backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5)', pointBorderColor: '#fff', data: [3762714, 11079381, 6223980, 2253066, 2772093] }, { label: '2016 - 2018', backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5)', pointBorderColor: '#DEB816', data: [3762714, 11079381, 6223980, 2253066, 2772093] }, ] };

            //This one doesn't work
            //var barData = parsedString;

            var barOptions = {
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }

            };


            var ctx2 = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d");
            new Chart(ctx2, { type: 'bar', data: barData, options: barOptions });

        }
    });
```

Comment: What you posted is not valid JSON, so it cannot be parsed by `JSON.parse`. It is however a valid JavaScript object literal. Use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON. Check out its list of "common errors". (I am assuming what you posted is the exact response returned by the server)

Comment: I think you don't need to stringify this, because, the value you assigned `var barData = { label.....` is not stringified one, try it using ` var parsedString = res.d;`

Comment: What Felix Kling wrote. JSON syntax is stricter then JavaScript object syntax. All _strings_ **MUST** be inside `"` not `'`. All object keys **MUST**  be _strings_.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last comma from your `json` file.

Comment: True but that's not the whole story

Answer (score -1):

Try doing `var barData = JSON.parse(parsedString);`. You are assigning string value to the barData whereas it is expecting JSON.

Comment: `res.d` is already the same as the result of your code. Why waste code and CPU effort stringify-ing and then parsing it back again? A process which always produces the output as its input is inherently pointless.

Answer (score -1):

The use of this line:

```
var barData = parsedString;
```

does not make a lot of sense. Your Chart doesn't want a *string*, it wants an *object*. You only stringified it so you could read it on the console.

```
new Chart(ctx2, { type: 'bar', data: res.d, options: barOptions });
```

is what you need to do - i.e. pass your result object directly to the chart.

P.S. the JSON shown in your question is invalid due to the last comma, but I'm going to assume that's typo because you maybe posted a reduced sample?
 I wouldn't expect your server software to produce invalid JSON like that, unless you're creating it by hand (e.g. using string concatenation) instead of a proper serialiser.